# How to implement presence validation for nested model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Full source code is here https://github.com/tenzan/postfile

*Creating a post working fine.*

I have a parent element "Conversation" and its child/nested element "Post".

[image]

When I click on "Create Post" with nothing entered, it should throw an error "Body can't be blank".

Instead, it giving another error:

[image]

`conversation.rb`:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  has_many :posts
end
```

`post.rb`:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :author, polymorphic: true
  has_rich_text :body

  validates :body, presence: :true
end
```

`posts_controller.rb`:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_conversation

    def create
        @post = @conversation.posts.new(post_params)
        @post.author = current_user
        
       respond_to do |format|
           
           if @post.save
            format.html { redirect_to @conversation }
           end
       end
    end

    private
    def set_conversation
        @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
    end

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

I show all posts within from conversation's `show.html.erb`:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Subject:</strong>
  <%= @conversation.subject %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Contact:</strong>
  <%= link_to @conversation.contact.name, @conversation.contact %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_conversation_path(@conversation) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', conversations_path %>

<div id="posts">
 <%= render @posts %>
</div>

<%= render partial: "posts/form", locals: { conversation: @conversation, post: Post.new } %>
```

Posts's partial `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_with model: [conversation, post], id: "form" do |form| %>

<div>
 <% form.object.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
  <div><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<br>

 <%= form.rich_text_area :body %>

 <%= form.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Full source code is here https://github.com/tenzan/postfile

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the error is not about validation, it's about unknown HTTP format

Answer (score 1):

You have this block in your `posts_controller`, which is where your error is arising:

```rb
respond_to do |format|           
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @conversation }
  end
end
```

Inside a `respond_to` block, you should have blocks identified by the `format` type, but you've added an `if` statement at that top level of the block where Rails is expecting a `format.xxx`. Move the `if` outside your `respond_to` block and you should be fine:

```rb
if @post.save
  respond_to do |format|           
    format.html { redirect_to @conversation }
  end
else
  DO SOMETHING WITH THE ERROR
end
```

(Also NB that you should handle the error if the post doesn't save, even if it's just to say "Sorry, please try again".)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give an example for `DO SOMETHING WITH THE ERROR` ?

Comment: It really depends on how your application works, but a common way to do it is to raise a flash error, which Rails will include in the returned HTML page: `flash[:error] = 'Could not save your post for reasons. Please try again'`. And then replace "for reasons" with actual reasons from the error returned by the failed save.

Comment: Thanks again.
In that case, I can move `respond_to do |format|` as follows. I also tried your way, but it's NOT giving an error. Also, as in the subject, the validation of empty body not working. I'd appreciate if you could update your answer with the working code instead of commenting.
```  
respond_to do |format|
     if @post.save  
        format.html { redirect_to @conversation }
          else
              format.html { flash[:error] = 'Could not save your post for reasons. Please try again' }
           end
end
```

Comment: I have updated my repo with the code in my comment.

Comment: Do you mean that you tried my suggestion and it didn't work? One other thing to try is to remove the `respond_to` block completely - you're only responding to html in any case so there's really no point. What happens then? (The error is arising around this section of code, given what you posted, so it's worth making sure.) NB No-one is going to create an entire app to try and reply to your question! It's your job as the person asking the question to narrow it down to the minimal reproducible example, as in the question guidelines.

Comment: Yes, your answer didn't work, and I'm not asking to make an entire app.

Comment: "Update your answer with working code", when the question includes so much code and covers so much ground, requires us to construct a lot of ground! I'd strongly suggest you try to narrow down where the error is arising (is it, as I suggested, that block?) and then look at exactly what's happening there. Then, we know exactly what's going on and can help more easily.

Comment: I was asking about `DO SOMETHING WITH THE ERROR` part.

Comment: I gave you working code for that (the flash message). If you want more than a flash message, you need once again to say what you actually need! (Also note that testing error cases is always hard, because getting the `@post.save` to fail is non-trivial!)

Comment: `flash[:error] = 'Could not save your post for reasons. Please try again'` - this part didn't work, when I hit on Create button.

Comment: Do you have the standard Rails flash code in your application layout? If so, it should work. But, anyway, you can return the error to your user however you like - even set a variable called `@error` and render it in the view as `<%= @error if @error.present? %>` if you like. The point is just that, if you have an `if` then you should consider what `else` happens. (And, don't forget that the error branch will only execute if the test fails, so you won't usually see it.)

Comment: Thanks again. I'll take a look later this week. On the other hand, when I try creating a blank post, it should throw an error "Body can't be blank", which is not working either. That was actually the subject of this post. I understand, there are more than one issues in my code.